# Django Dajax vs Dajaxice

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax

This may be a very silly question but I'm looking at implementing ajax in my django project and the big plugin seems to be dajax/dajaxice however I can't for the life of me distinguish between the two. Could someone clear this up a little for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dajaxice is the core of the project, to quote the website:

'Its main goal is to trivialize the asynchronous communication between the django server side code and your js code.'

This means that a django / python method on the server like:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def multiply(request, a, b):
  result = int(a) * int(b)
  return simplejson.dumps({'result' : result})
```

Can be called on the client using javascript:

```
var result = Dajaxice.calcualator.multiply(1, 2);
console.log("Dajax says 1 * 2 = "+result);
```

Dajax provides a series of tools that incorporate dajaxice but requires less Javascript to be used, instead relying on more Python. The multiple example is [here](http://www.dajaxproject.com/multiply/).

I have used dajaxice on a few projects without using dajax. Also worth mentioning is [Tasty Pie](http://tastypieapi.org/) this creates a similar interface on the server, and using JQuery ajax helper functions like `.post()`, client side, little additional code is required in javascript compared to dajaxice.

Comment: I have a tastypie API built already for use with mobile apps, am I correct in understanding that I can use this API to POST ajax requests to?

Answer (score 5):

ATTENTION:

> Should I use django-dajax or django-dajaxice?
>
> In a word, No. I created these projects 4 years ago as a cool tool in
>   order to solve one specific problems I had at that time.
>
> These days using these projects is a bad idea.

https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax